# System Verilog : wire input for bits part indexing

Tags: arrays, parameters, bit-manipulation, verilog, system-verilog

I have the following code:

```
module rotate
(
input wire [5:0]       index,// tells how many bits to rotate
input [31:0]      a,
output [31:0]     b
);
```

I want to implement this assign statement for left rotate:

```
assign b  = {a[32-index-1 : 0], a[31: 32-index] ;

..
..
..

endmodule
```

The above assignment will not work since wire/logic signals are evaluated during simulation time. I am not able to use parameters.

I tried converting wire to integer and then do assignment, still its not working.

```
int i1 = index ;
assign assign b[i1] = a[i1] ; // this worked
assign b[i1-1 : 0] = a[i1-1 : 0] ; //not worked
```

I implemented using for loop inside always_comb but I want a simpler method like concatenation operation etc.

Please help with a suitable way.

Comment: A wire is only 1 bit wide (by default), so `input wire        index` doesn't make any sense. If you use an `int` then you can now represent a number more than 1 bit wide. However, there are two more problems: on the left hand side of the `=` you cannot change which bits your drive; on the right hand side of the `=`, you cannot vary the width like that. What are you trying to actually achieve?

Comment: I have modified the question. I want to do a rotate operation using the concatenation operator and the rotate count will be specified by an input.

Answer (score 0):

> I want to do a rotate operation using the concatenation operator and the rotate count will be specified by an input.

You were very close, especially with using two concatenated a's. All you have to do is use the `+:` operator:

```
wire [63:0] a_twice = {a,a}; 
assign b = a_twice[ index +: 32]; 

The +: operator gives you the bits from index to index+31:
3322222222221111111111          3322222222221111111111
1098765432109876543210987654321010987654321098765432109876543210
           <-------------  +32  ----------> index=21
```

Comment: Thank you . I have one more question can we use -: as well like: a_twice [ index -: 0 ]

Comment: Not in that form. The number behind the +: or -: is the **length** of the vector. You can not use a length of 0.